# NSTextField add cancel button

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield, nsbutton

Using iOS and a UISearchBar you can have a nice little cancel button setup within the text field similar to this:

[image]

(Note I found the image on another post and the 'argh!' is not relevant in my case).

Now in my case i'm using cocoa and a NSTextField and i'm wondering what the easiest way to have something similar added would be. Worse case scenario I will create a custom NSTextField with an image/button on it, but I would prefer to not reinvent the wheel if I am missing an obvious way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow overlooked the `NSSearchField` component which does basically exactly this.